# What is the NEL line terminator?

Tags: javascript, android, terminator

I know CR, LF, and CRLF, but I have never encountered NEL. I encountered this line terminator for the first time today. No particularly detailed descriptive documents were found. Will it cause some request resources to be garbled? The JavaScript file I obtained from the Android client is garbled.

Manually change it to LF.

Answer (score 0):

The `NEL` (Next Line) line terminator is a Unicode character with the code 0x85 in hexadecimal, or 133 in decimal. For more information, see [Compart](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+0085).

In the EBCDIC (Extended Binary Coded Decimal Interchange Code) encoding system, which was primarily used in IBM mainframes in the 1960s, `NL` (0x15 in EBCDIC) is mapped to `NEL` (0x85 in Unicode). This is explained on Wikipedia's [newline page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline):

> For example: NL is part of EBCDIC, which uses code 0x15; it is normally mapped to **Unicode NEL, 0x85**, which is a control character in the C1 control set. As such, it is defined by ECMA 48, and recognized by encodings compliant with ISO/IEC 2022 (which is equivalent to ECMA 35). C1 control set is also compatible with ISO-8859-1. The approach taken in the Unicode standard allows round-trip transformation to be information-preserving while still enabling applications to recognize all possible types of line terminators.
>
> Recognizing and using the newline **codes greater than 0x7F** (**NEL**, LS and PS) is not often done. They are multiple bytes in UTF-8, and the code for NEL has been used as the ellipsis (…) character in Windows-1252. For instance:
>
> - **ECMAScript** accepts LS and PS as line breaks, but **considers U+0085 (NEL) whitespace instead of a line break**.
> - JSON allows LS and PS characters within strings, while ECMAScript prior to ES2019 treated them as newlines, and therefore illegal syntax.
> - YAML no longer recognizes them as line breaks as of version 1.2, in order to be compatible with JSON.
> - Windows Notepad, the default text editor of Microsoft Windows, does not treat any of NEL, LS, or PS as line breaks.
> - gedit, the default text editor of the GNOME desktop environment, treats LS and PS, but not NEL, as line breaks.

Therefore, `NEL` may not be processed correctly in some programs.

Other Wikipedia pages also discuss `NEL`. For example, [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) explains:

> The most common newline convention used with EBCDIC is to use a **NEL (NEXT LINE)** code between lines. Converters to other encodings often replace NEL with LF or CR/LF, even if there is a NEL in the target encoding. This causes the LF and NEL to translate to the same character and be unable to be distinguished.

The mapping of `NL` in EBCDIC to `NEL` in Unicode is detailed in the [EBCDIC section on NL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC#NL):

> NL (EBCDIC 15) (Unicode paring 0085) New Line: Line break. Default mapping (0085) matches ISO/IEC 6429's NEL. Mappings sometimes swapped with Line Feed (EBCDIC 0x25) in accordance with UNIX line breaking convention.[10]

And [C0 and C1 control codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#NEL) further clarifies that `NEL` is:

> Equivalent to CR+LF. Used to mark end-of-line on some IBM mainframes.

So, yes, using the `NEL` line terminator (Unicode character 0x85) can potentially cause some resources to become garbled in certain contexts. This is because `NEL` is not properly processed by all software or programming languages.